# sql to dataframe in function

Tags: python, function, read-sql

new to functions so obviously there are lack of knowledge around the basics of this.
I want to create a function which fetch data from sql server but I don't know how to pass it to a dataframe. This dataframe will later be used by other functions
This what I have done so far.

```
class Inputdata:
 
  def __init__():
      driver_path = ("Driver={SQL Server};"
                    "Server=xxx;"
                    "Database=xxx;"
                    "Trusted_Connection=xxx;")       
  def select(self, query, con):
      con = pyodbc.connect(driver_path)
      
      query = """   Select  * FROM TABLE """

       
      result = pd.read_sql(query,con)
      return result
```

Comment: so what is exactly your question? you run it and see some error? please specify it

Comment: What I want is a dataframe named "result" with the data fetched from sql server. But it does not generat any such dataframe with name "result". And no error either.....

Comment: how do you run it? could you please provide full code

Comment: Part from importing packages pandas and pyodbc this all the code I run in one sequence.

Comment: However there's red  error dot (spider) on the line "con = pyodbc.connect(driver_path)" saying "undefined name "driver_path".

Comment: you only created the class. now you need to make some "main" function, put inside something like inp = Inputdata() and then res = inp.select(...) 
however it's really very basic parts. i would recommend some python beginners course

Answer (score 1):

Try this, but adopt to your needs please.

```
def get_sql_data():
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver=SQL Server;Server=enter_your_server;Database=enter_your_database;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()

    df = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT *
                              FROM table ''', cnxn)

    cnxn.close()
    return df

df = get_sql_data()
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

I added `self` in `__init__(self)`. And I removed `query` from `def select(self, query)` because you define it inside function so sending it as parameter is useless.

---

Inside `__init__` you create local variable `driver_path` and it doesn't exist in other functions.

You have to use `self.driver_path` to access it in other functions in class.

```
class Inputdata:
 
  #def __init__():  # OLD VERSION
  def __init__(self):
      self.driver_path = ("Driver={SQL Server};"
                          "Server=xxx;"
                          "Database=xxx;"
                          "Trusted_Connection=xxx;")       

  #def select(self, query): # OLD VERSION
  def select(self):  # you don't need `con`, and you don't need `query` because you define it inside function
      con = pyodbc.connect(self.driver_path)
      
      query = "SELECT  * FROM TABLE "
       
      result = pd.read_sql(query, con)
      return result

# --- main ---

x = Inputdata()
data = x.select()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Eventually you could create `con` in `__init__` and it would need `self.` to access it in other functions

```
class Inputdata:
 
  #def __init__():  # OLD VERSION
  def __init__(self):
      driver_path = ("Driver={SQL Server};"
                     "Server=xxx;"
                     "Database=xxx;"
                     "Trusted_Connection=xxx;")       
      self.con = pyodbc.connect(driver_path)

  #def select(self, query):  # OLD VERSION
  def select(self):  # you don't need `con`, and you don't need `query` because you define it inside function
      
      query = "SELECT  * FROM TABLE "
       
      result = pd.read_sql(query, self.con)
      
      return result

# --- main ---

x = Inputdata()
data = x.select()
```

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate that you took time to look in to it!

Comment: Hi again, one question. tried to call the function by                                                                a = Inputdat
data = a.select()                                                                                                                           but getting error "self not defined " tried many different solutions but seems not get it....

Comment: you should create new question on new page and show full error message and what code makes this problem. I don't know if I see where is the probleme. As for me you simply forgot `()` in line `a = Inputdata()`. But `select()` also need arguments

Comment: when I look at this code now then I see it needs `self` in `__init__`. And it doesn't need `query` in `select()` because it replaced by query inside `function`.

Comment: I added this in code.